# How to deal with multiple composed/related conditions?

Tags: software-design

Which is the best approach to deal with multiple composed/related conditions. Let's say that exists this conditions:

```
Condition A
Condition B
Condition C
...
Condition G
```

Some of these conditions are related, for example, `Condition A` and `Condition G` and `Condition D`composes a condition, `Condition C` and `Condition F` composes a condition, `F` with `A` another, etc.

If I do it with  `if/else if` the code looks like crap. So, which's the best way to do that in an ordered and maintainable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create temporary or derived conditions.

```
Condition_X = condition_a && condition_b && condition_c
Condition_Y = condition_e && condition_f && condition_g

If Condition_X == FALSE && Condition_Y then...
```